# How to change "star review" position on Woocommerce store Page

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to change the position of the "star review" on the shop page

previous [image: screenshot 1]

I added CSS code

```
.star rating {
      float: right !important;
      margin-top: -18px !important;
}
```

[image: screenshot 2] like this, I like

So, the problem is in the single product page

before I add the CSS code
[image: screenshot 3] like this

after I added the CSS code the position changed
be like this

[image: screenshot 4]

how to display "star reviews" as in screenshot 2 and not break the position of "star reviews" on single product pages

Sorry maybe my question is difficult for you to understand,Thank you

**Additional**

Previously the theme I used by default didn't have "star reviews" on the shop page, only on single product page.

so i added this code in functions.php

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'add_star_rating' );
function add_star_rating()
{
global $woocommerce, $product;
$average = $product->get_average_rating();

echo '<div class="star-rating"><span style="width:'.( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' ).'</span></div>';
}
```

star review shown as in screenshot 1

Comment: The current CSS you are using doesn't seem to be valid. Correct CSS Syntax `float: none|left|right|initial|inherit;`. To answer your question, your selector is too specific, so you need to extend your selector with an selector that can be found on the shop page, and not on the single product page. For instance `.post-type-archive .star`

Comment: I've edited the CSS in the question

Comment: I tested with this CSS
and it works fine
`.woocommerce ul.products li.product .star-rating {
    float: right !important;
    margin-top: -18px !important;
}`
Thank you for your answer

Comment: from the code I added in functions.php
is it possible after "star review" there is a number of reviews for example like this (2)
if there are no reviews, then leave the display as before

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the star div on that specific page. You are targeting star review div, so it will change on all pages. Try adding something like .archive before your selector like: .archive .star-rating {}

You can find the page selector if you inspect the page you want to change in the body class.

Comment: I just changed the details of the problem in the question, maybe you can help

Comment: I tested with this CSS
and it works fine
`.woocommerce ul.products li.product .star-rating {
    float: right !important;
    margin-top: -18px !important;
}`
Thank you for your answer